# Organizing same website in different languages on a single domain

Tags: url

I have my personal website made with Sphinx. It generates static HTML pages. Currenty, the content is just in English or German only. I would like to expand this to multiple languages. I do not know how to structure my URLs, yet.

The following should be done:

- Static folders like `/_download`, `/_download` and `/_images` must still be on the server only once, I do not have that much space.
- The languages might be on equal footing, but that is not that important.
- Old URLs still work without a problem and default to English. I do not want to cause a single 404 error.

I currently have the following ideas:

- Put the English site on `` `example.de/ ``, put the German site on `de.example.de/` and redirect `de.example.de/_download` to `example.de/_download` with a `.htaccess` file.
- Put the English site on `example.de/` and put the German site on `example.de/de/`. Redirects as above.
- English site on `en.example.de/` and German on `de.example.de/`. And redirect for all languages.
- English site on `example.de/en/` and German on `example.de/de/`. Redirects as above.

What would make the most sense?

Comment: If your domain ends with `de`, it would only make sense to have german as the default, and english in foobar.de/en.

Comment: Valid point, I will try the user's language, then default to German.

Comment: @MightyPork I use Piwik for tracking now, and the majority seems to speak German, so that was the right way to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the .de domain suffix indicates Germany, many folks associate .de with German. Displaying English by default adds confusion, which acts as a roadblock to those seeking other languages.

Setting the English site on `en.example.de` and German on `de.example.de` is most consistent, and will be most easily intuited by your multi-lingual audience.

Another option, which was not listed by the OP, would be to set the English site on `example.de/en`, and German on `example.de/de`.